# vb.net code has syntax errors after conversion

Tags: vb.net

vb.net code has syntax errors after conversion

I need to convert c# code into vb.net from http://highcharts.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20column%20chart

using online tool http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

after conversion vb.net code as below

```
hcFrutas.Title = New Title("Consumo de Frutas")
hcFrutas.SubTitle = New SubTitle("Agrupados por tipo de fruta")


'Defining Axis
hcFrutas.YAxis.Add(New YAxisItem() With { _
Key .title = New Title("Unidades") _
})
hcFrutas.XAxis.Add(New XAxisItem() With { _
Key .categories = New () {"Macas", "Laranjas", "Peras", "Bananas", "Uvas"} _
})

'data 
Dim series = New Collection(Of serie)()
series.Add(New Serie() With { _
Key .name = "Andre", _
Key .data = New Object() {4, 15, 5, 17, 14} _
})
series.Add(New Serie() With { _
Key .name = "Ivan", _
Key .data = New Object() {4, 25, 6, 12, 6} _
})
series.Add(New Serie() With { _
Key .name = "Marina", _
Key .data = New Object() {7, 19, 2, 34, 5} _
})
series.Add(New Serie() With { _
Key .name = "Camila", _
Key .data = New Object() {3, 14, 6, 21, 9} _
})

'configuring Visual 
hcFrutas.PlotOptions = New Core.PlotOptions.PlotOptionsColumn() With { _
Key .borderColor = "#dedede", _
Key .borderRadius = 4 _
}

'bind 
hcFrutas.DataSource = series
hcFrutas.DataBind()
please help in resolving above errors in the vb.net code
actually json string is unable to convert in vb.net
```

Comment: WHAT syntax errors do you get?

Comment: Code doesn't seem that long nor complicated... why don't you simply try converting it manually instead of using a tool ? That way you may have a better view on the problems...

Comment: I think it could be complaining about the whitespace between `Key` and `.xxxxx`

Comment: You need to post the errors, we do not have a crystal ball

Comment: StackOverflow is not suited for questions that contain nothing but a large code dump and "It doesn't work. Please fix it". We can't read your mind or see your screen from where we are, and expecting us to guess is very unreasonable when you're asking us for free help (and have the error messages right in front of you).

Comment: When I see a question saying that there was an error without specifying what the error was, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" 9 times out of 9. Unless you're using an Apple II, error messages actually say something other than just "Error", and they do that for a reason: The information is useful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete all occurences of `Key`. The `With` statement does not need a reference within the block. E.g.:

```
hcFrutas.YAxis.Add(New YAxisItem() With { _
    .title = New Title("Unidades") _
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot Nico - Really thank for understanding my problem and giving precise solution.